# SSD App Needed?

Tags: app, ssd, suggestion, mobile-phone, mobile

Hey all,

I know there has been multiple threads on having groups on Sound Cloud, Twitter, Poll Surveys, etc... But as SSD has been becoming more populated, I feel like there could be a pretty slick app that could be made and connected to the forum.

I find using Safari or any other browser is a bit wonky with zooming in and out, tapping on the fields and trying to navigate the tabs. Even though SSD is pretty simple already, I think an App could be beneficial for a more Mobile friendly environment.

Its possible that I could come up with the interface for this, but the programming I wouldnt be able to produce. I do have a number of friends who program apps, but I would need the go ahead from a moderator of SSD.

Comment or Bump if you think this should be done, or comment on if you think it would even be worth it. I do know that sometimes I find myself away from a computer or without my laptop and could use the ability to ask a quick question. It could help if one was in the field for a few days and needed a suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Ill throw up screenshots of a mock interface for people to look at in a few.

Comment: @C3Sound: Heck yeah.

Comment: Make sure the log-out sound effect is the wilhelm scream.

Comment: @utopia love that! would be hilarious. 

Comment: This is definitely great idea! 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a big fat eager "yes please" from me :-)

That would be amazing. Let me know if I can do anything. My email is andrew [at]soundplusdesign [dot]com

Answer (score 4):

Yes!

Fumbled from my phone.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype is great but needs a search button. :-)

Comment: Haha, picky picky! I threw it together real fast dood - itll have one, only if the project is green lighted.

Comment: hehe I'm sure it will! It's a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use it. I'd probably enjoy using it if it had all the functionality of the web page. I don't necessarily mind viewing SSD on my iPod touch, I'd say the main drawback is writing posts/comments. If you can improve that experience, I'd be all about it.

Comment: @Steve Urban what about posting comments and answering do you not like on your mobile? - I'll try and come up with a solution. 

Comment: The comment window is a little wonky. It overflows past the screen, so I'm always scrolling side to side or resizing it to fit and squinting at the 6 point font. Long posts are difficult because the comment window is a static size, and if you type more than the 4 lines, there's no page scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea, but wouldn't it be much easier and quicker to have the website detect the type of browser (via User Agent) and display a compact version optimized for mobile browsers?
This is how loads of websites work, and it is sort of supported by Stack Exchange, the platform that SSD runs on (see stackmobile.com).

Plus, the Stack Exchange API is read only at the moment, so that means that a real app would not be able to add answers or comments, only read them ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74366/stack-overflow-mobile-site)).

Comment: @EMV It depends on how it's compacted and presented. I would need to see an example of SSD in this form. Apps also prove useful for more functions that could open new ways of reaching out to the community of designers, not including showing up for free download on the iTunes store.

Comment: Could you provide this example for SSD?

Comment: @C3Sound: I agree that a real app is nicer, but it's also exponentially more work. So my suggestion would be to look at a phone-friendly web-version before (or while) we start hoping for an app.
And my second point still stands, the API doesn't support writing so it's currently not possible without a load of trickery.
For an example, you could open http://www.stackmobile.com/site.php?site=stackoverflow on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

That would be great to have.  Needed it two weeks ago though, where were you then?

Comment: I'm on the job - so far it could be a handy reference app - I'll post updates soon!

Answer (score 0):

Only rich sound designers can afford smartphones

Comment: Heh. Well your phone is a business expense, and as such, you can deduct the cost of it from tax ;)

Answer (score 0):

put it up on kickstarter!!